# Custom UITableViewCell which reacts on touchDown

Tags: ios, uitableview

How to make `UITableViewCell`, which invokes `tableView` delegate's methods (`willSelectRowAtIndexPath` and `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`) on `touchDown` event (immediately after touch unlike `TouchUpInside` does it)?

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom cell and add an event handler to it using:

```
- (void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents.
```

Use the **UIControlEventTouchDown** constant as the third parameter. You can do anything you want in your own event handler. You might set your table view's allowSelection property to **NO**.

Comment: actually UITableViewCell isn't a UIControl child so it doesn't have 'addTarget:action:...' method.